# How to use xml:lang in xsd/xml?

Tags: xml, internationalization, xsd, phpstorm

I have the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.vibrogym.com/schema"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.vibrogym.com/schema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xs:import schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd" 
               namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"/>

    <xs:complexType name="localizedNameType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="exercise">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" 
                            type="localizedNameType" 
                            minOccurs="1" 
                            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exercise xmlns="http://www.vibrogym.com/schema">
    <name xml:lang="en">test</name>
</exercise>
```

PHPStorm gives the following validation error: `Element name doesn't have the required attribute lang`.

Is PHPStorm correct in giving me the validation error? If so, what am I doing wrong?

*UPDATE*

Apparently the `use="required"` attribute on `localizedNameType` type triggers the validation error; Why is this wrong?

Comment: Apart from PHPStorm's complaint, your example looks ok.  Would PHPStorm perhaps be satisfied if you were to add the namespace declaration (`xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`) to the `name` element in the XML instance?   Eg: `<name xml:lang="en" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">test</name>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PHPStorm is not correct; the document is valid against the schema you give.  As kjhughes has speculated, the problem may be related to errors in its treatment of the `xml` namespace. If adding the namespace declaration he suggests causes PHPStorm to accept the document, then you have two bugs to report: the failure to validate this example correctly, and failure to report a namespace well formedness error on the version with a namespace declaration for the `xml` namespace.  (The prefix `xml` is reserved, so you're not allowed to declare a namespace with prefix `xml`.)